# Prevent application error message from appearing "A Task's exception(s) were not observed by Waiting on the Task"

Tags: c#, .net, task

I am almost definitely missing something super obvious, but I have a task that I'd like to fire and forget. I'm kicking off the Task using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and I'm observing the `UnobservedTaskException` with:

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs eventArgs) =>
{
     eventArgs.SetObserved();
     eventArgs.Exception.Handle(
          ex =>
          {
               Console.WriteLine(ex);
               return true;
           });
};
```

The `Console.WriteLine(ex)` line is being hit, but before it's hit I get the message:

[image]

I've looked at several questions dealing with the message and they all suggest observing the exception like I've done above and/or using `ContinueWith` with `OnlyOnFault`, but no combination has yet worked for me at both catching the error AND preventing that message from being displayed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sometimes your IDE has `Exception Settings` that are turned on for all exceptions, even those caught or handled, have you tried resetting your `Exception Settings` to default? In `VS`: `Debug\Windows\Exception Settings\Restore the list to default settings`

Comment: @SerjSagan The settings appeared to be at default, but just to be sure I restored them to default and it did not change the outcome. Interestingly, even when I chose to have it halt the run when `System.AggregateException` occurred (which I believe is the exception type of the unobserved task), it also did not alter the outcome.